# Optimize an image in Angular

Tags: angular, optimization, upload, photo

I have a website that the user can upload your profile photo, but some photos are heavy, and i want to revert this problem.

I made these functions, but it doesn't work it.

```
async uploadPhoto() {
    if (this.photoInput.nativeElement.files.length) {
      await Promise.all([this.uploadOriginal(), this.uploadOptimized()])
      this.post.photo.mobile = this.post.photo.mobile || this.post.photo.original;
    }
  }

async uploadOriginal() {
    const { width, height, extension } = this.originalImageData;
    const path = `post-photo__u-${this.user.uid}__p-${this.post.createdAt.getTime()}__${width}x${height}.${extension}`;
    const originalSnapshot = await this.upload(path, this.photoInput.nativeElement.files[0]);
    this.post.photo.original = await originalSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  }

async uploadOptimized() {
    const { width, height, extension } = this.originalImageData;
    if (width > 768 || height > 768) {
      const optimized = await this.resizeImage(768, height > width);
      const optimizedPath = `post-photo__u-${this.user.uid}__p-${this.post.createdAt.getTime()}__${optimized.width}x${optimized.height}.${extension}`;

      const optimizedSnapshot = await this.upload(optimizedPath, optimized.blob);
      this.post.photo.mobile = await optimizedSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    }
  }
```

I am open to other attempts to try to optimize the photo.

Comment: What doesnt work?

Comment: the photo continues the same size that the user upload

Comment: can you please  generate stack-blitz for more understanding about issue ?